# How do I display the whole background image from a div? (bootstrap/css)

Tags: html, css

How do I display the whole size of image in a div. in css.
When I import the the image through the HTML file, it views the whole image but I want to put something on it so I imported it in css and made it the background image. Now the size is like a banner from youtube ;-; .
Here are images to see what I mean. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udq7E.jpg
Only multiple 
 tags can view the image, but I know that is wrong.
Thank you

```
.header{
background-image: url(Image url...);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="" class="img-fluid ">
  <div>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you've forgotten to add `height: 100vh` to your
   `div.header`.
2. You've added another `img` tag and I don't understand what is it. If it's the same as the background, then delete it.
3. You can simply do *all in one* : `background: url(foo) center/cover no-repeat`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080) center/cover no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="" class="img-fluid ">
  <div>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would appreciate you if you up vote and accept my answer(Check icon under the vote icons)

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow. Also I cannot upvote it said I need a specific reputation I think. But I accepted your answer

Comment: I appreciate you! Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `center` in CSS does not guarantee that the image will take the whole height/width. You have basically two options to make sure that your image will be uncropped:

```css
.header {
    background-image: url(Image url...);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;

    /* Use one out of the two following */

    background-size: contains; /* this will leave uncovered bands vertically or horizontally, making sure that the whole image is visible. No deformation */
    background-size: cover; /* Will make sure that the whole space is taken. Will deform the image if needed */
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) you will find more information about this CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it while having `img` in HTML. You can make `.header` div position `relative` and image and heading position `absolute`. Add image in HTML gives you the ability to change the image dynamically. You can check in the demo: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lahzqrv/)

> HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KZNUrTV.jpeg" class="img-fluid ">
  <div>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```